# AWS S3 : Do Lifecycle rules accept regex?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket with "folders" folder1, folder2, folder3, folder4. In folder2 and folder3 there is a "new" folder. I need to delete everything in "new", older than 1 day. Can I do that with a rule like /*/new/ ? Some guys say they have seen such rules work in the past, but that particular definition does nothing.

(In the real bucket there are folder1, folder2 ... folder3001 so I can't make rules for every folder, so please don't suggest that. The above example is for simplicity only.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The PUT livecycle API takes a "Prefix", which as the name says is a prefix, not a regex.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTlifecycle.html

There is also a limit of 1000 rules per bucket.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html

You could change your folder structure so that keys look like "new/folderN".